# Hello so I am creating a small game and i need to instantiate multiple prefabs but i do not know how to make make instantiate return a game Object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an array "undefined" and I need to spawn the game objects in the array
I know that instantiate return an object but I want it to return a game object

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] myObjects;
    public float interval;
    float timer;

    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer >= interval)
        {
            Instantiate(myObjects, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            timer -= interval;
        }

    }


}
```

I get this error:
Assets\Scripts\ObjectSpawner.cs(16,13): error CS0311: The type 'UnityEngine.GameObject[]' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Object.Instantiate(T, Vector3, Quaternion)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'UnityEngine.GameObject[]' to 'UnityEngine.Object'.

i would really appreciate the help

What i tried:

Instantiate(myObjects, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

and

GameObject newObject = Instantiate(myObjects, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

Comment: The error is stating that you cannot pass an array to instantiate.  Instead loop over your collection of objects and spawn them individually.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the array in **Instantiate**.
You need to pass `object` not `array`
if u want to instantiate the objects in the array try to use foreach loop example :

`foreach (GameObject gameObject in myObjects) { Instantiate(...) }`

And just an additional thing that may help you:
I saw you are using `public array`. If you do that just to expose it to the editor you can just use `[SerializeField]` attribute.  If you do that so another script can use it, use a getter method.